# Kinetic JS - how to destroy a sprite

Tags: kineticjs

In Kinetic JS, I want to destroy a sprite and remove it from the layer

The documentation says kinetic.node has the following method:

> destroy()
>   remove and destroy node

the documentation also states for kinetic.sprite:

> Methods borrowed from class Kinetic.Node:
>   ..., destroy,...

I assumed that 'borrowed from' meant 'inherited from', and thought that I would therefore be able to do:

```
mysprite.destroy()
```

but this gives me a message telling me that kinetic.sprite has no such method.

I was worried that it might be my version of kineticJS that was out of date, as my version is quite old (v3.10.0), but when I try using the latest version of kineticJS it causes an error in another part of my application, when I try to call the onFrame() method of my kinetic.stage object, telling me that this method does not exist on Kinetic.Stage.

If anyone has any ideas why I can't call destroy on my kinetic.sprite object, or why when I upgrade to the latest version of kineticJS I am getting an error calling kinetic.stage.onframe then I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: also, I think onFrame has been replaced with Animation.

Comment: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-animate-position-tutorial/

Comment: thanks! i will vote you up 2moro - i have reached my limit today :) (again i mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this - it may work with your version

```
  LayerName.remove(mysprite);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response: That's what I'm currently doing as a temporary measure so I could move on, but to stay in keeping with the way I've structured my OO application I'd like ideally to call a method on the sprite to destroy itself. I think this should be possible based on the KineticJS docs...

Comment: if you upgrade you can destroy. only version 4.3 supports the destroy method. do i get a vote? :)